# How do i can extend or re-use Gallery Js Component of module Catalog in right way

Tags: magento2, javascript, widgets, component

This component is located in `Magento_Catalog/js/product-gallery`

```
map: {
    '*': {
        categoryForm:       'Magento_Catalog/catalog/category/form',
        newCategoryDialog:  'Magento_Catalog/js/new-category-dialog',
        categoryTree:       'Magento_Catalog/js/category-tree',
        productGallery:     'Magento_Catalog/js/product-gallery',
        baseImage:          'Magento_Catalog/catalog/base-image-uploader',
        productAttributes:  'Magento_Catalog/catalog/product-attributes'
    }
}
```

I already copied the same file with a different name but when my component runs, it does not work properly like the original one. Official [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html) mentions to extend it, but i can't make it work successfully
It would be more helpful if the core teams explain more details for me as to how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

1 . Initialize js components

```
var config = {
   "map": {
        '*': {
           "productGallery2": 'Vendor_CustomModule/js/product-gallery'
        }
   },
   "shim": {
       "ves/productGallery2": ["productGallery","baseImage"]
   },
   "deps": [
       "Magento_Catalog/js/product-gallery",
       "Magento_Catalog/catalog/base-image-uploader"
   ],
   "paths": {
       "your_namespace/productGallery2": "Vendor_CustomModule/js/product-gallery"
    }
};
```

2. Extend widget

```
define([
'jquery',
'mage/template',
'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
'jquery/ui',
'baseImage',
'mage/translate',
'domReady!'
 ], function (jQuery, mageTemplate, alert) {
"use strict";

jQuery.widget('yourNamespace.productGallery', {
    options: {
        //init vars
    },

    //override original method
    original: function() {
        this._super();
        //modify code
    }

    return jQuery.yourNamespace.productGallery;
});
```

Clear `var/cache`, `var/generation`, `pub/static/adminhtml` , `pub/static/_requirejs` for update
I got new issues . But better should post it in another question